# How can I get fail2ban to install on Centos 7.4?

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, fail2ban

I've done `yum install epel-release` and this shows in my repolist:

```
repo id                                                     repo name                                                                                 status
base/7/x86_64                                               CentOS-7 - Base                                                                            9,591
epel/x86_64                                                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                            12,219
extras/7/x86_64                                             CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                            329
updates/7/x86_64                                            CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                         1,698
```

When I ask whether fail2ban is available, the answer is yes...

```
Available Packages
fail2ban.noarch                                                               0.9.7-1.el7                                                               epel
```

But when I install, it seems to attempt a different version and then has issues with an apparently too-new version of Python.

```
Error: Package: fail2ban-0.9.6-1.el6.1.noarch (epel)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
       Installed: python-2.7.5-58.el7.x86_64 (installed)
           python(abi) = 2.7
           python(abi) = 2.7
       Available: python34-3.4.5-4.el6.i686 (epel)
           python(abi) = 3.4
```

It gives these two options to work around the problem, but I'm not sure how wise either of those is.

```
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Odd, that looks like fail2ban from epel for centos 6, but repolist says 7 in the description.

Comment: Yes, and some of the Q&A I found mentioned similar and suggested uninstalling the repo, cleaning yum, and re-installing, which I did, but the result didn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While checking for any package updates I noticed the epel repository was erroring with a 404.

Once again I removed the repository, cleaned, and re-installed. A different version of the repository resulted and my first attempt to install fail2ban completed successfully.